# mongodb list products under each category

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Have to list the categories and products as shown below, have to  retrieve the data from mongodb.

category A

Product 1
Product 2
Product 3

Category B

Product 4
Product 5
Product 6

> Category in db:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "62c827b5a427b63741da9175"
  },
  "name": {
    "en": "Home"
  }
}
```

> Product in db:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "648714ca2c67a70008c616db"
  },
  "categories": [
    {
      "$oid": "649911fc0e298800088d0214"
    },
  ],
  "image": [1000047887.png",1000047889.jpg"
  ],
  "tag": [
    "[]"
  ],
  "category": {
    "$oid": "648702f958cc2d0008cda715"
  },
  "name": "Product A"
}
```

> Need to get data as:

```
[
  {
   "category_name": "Abc",
   "products": [{
      "product_name": "cvb",
      ....
    },
    {
      "product_name": "cvb",
      ....
    }
    ]
  },
  {
   "category_name": "Abc",
   "products": [{
      "product_name": "cvb",
      ....
    },
    {
      "product_name": "cvb",
      ....
    }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: In the prooduct collection, you have an array, and a single field for `categories` .  From which one do you need to make the connection?  Can a product be in several categories if there are several ids in that array?

Comment: @Ruben Vega - Product can't be in multiple categories, from categories field we can make the connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, all you need to do is use an `aggregation` with `$lookup`, joining the 2 collections by the category id.

```
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "product",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "category",
      "as": "products"
    }
  }
```

You can then add a `$project` step in the aggregation to format your output.

```
  {
    "$project": {
      "category_name": "$name.en",
      "products": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$products",
          "as": "temp",
          "in": {
            "product_name": "$$temp.name"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

[Playground Example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zhgRgR53GjP)

Comment: Thanks Ruben Vega, your solution worked.